# Xamarin Forms Android DatePicker - want only spinner to show, but calendar is as well

Tags: c#, android, datepicker, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working in Xamarin Forms and I have a DatePicker set up.  I am trying to only show the spinner part of the DatePicker; however, the calendar part also shows up.  I've looked through many other questions similar to mine, and tried a bunch of things that haven't worked.  (Also, I am using an emulator that uses API 22 and a lot of posts I've seen say that there were issues with 24+, so I don't think this would apply.)

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:navigationIcon">@drawable/BackChevronBlue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/back_button_color</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
       <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
       <item name="android:spinnersShown">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
       <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
       <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
       <item name="android:spinnersShown">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! TIA!

Comment: You could refer to: https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/how-to-create-a-custom-dropdown-control-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the fields were swapped for some reason.  When I changed the following fields, only the spinner shows:

```
<item name="android:calendarViewShown">true</item>
<item name="android:spinnersShown">false</item>
```